# GAM Parameter Estimates and Shrinkage

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I run the following GAM model in R using the `mgcv` pacakge:

```
my_fit <- mgcv::gam(mpg ~ s(disp, bs = "ts", k = 15), gaussian(), mtcars, method = "REML")
```

As far as I understand the help page of `mgcv::smooth.construct.ts.smooth.spec`, setting `bs = "ts"` shrinks the coefficients of the fit towards zero. Looking at `summary(my_fit)` returns

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf    Ref.df F     p-value    
s(disp) 4.251  14     14.23 <2e-16 ***
```

so the effective degree of freedoms are 4.251. Do I understand this correctly, out of the `k = 15` basis functions, about 9 are shrunk to zero ($15 - 1 - 9 = 5 \approx 4.251$)? However, `my_fit$coefficients` returns 15 coefficients for `s(disp)`, and most of them are quite far from zero. I would have expected either only about 5 coefficients or 15 coefficients and about 10 are close to zero. Where do I see the shrinkage? Or is there no shrinkage going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 14 basis functions here, not 15; one is removed when the identifiability (sum-to-zero) constraint is applied to the basis.

All of the weights (coefficients) for the basis functions are shrunk to some extent if the smooth is penalized. As there are 14 basis functions there will always be 14 coefficients associated with this smooth regardless of the amount of shrinkage. If the smoothing parameter, $\lambda$, is sufficiently high, those coefficients will be shrunk to be effectively zero.

However, there is no reason to presume that 9 or 10 of the coefficients (in your case) will be all shrunk to effective zero. The penalty is controlling the wiggliness of the estimated smooth and that can counterintuitively require non-zero values of all the coefficients to achieve a fit that uses 4 to 5 effective degrees of freedom (EDF).

The point that the help page is making is that the estimated **function** (the page uses the word "term") *can* be shrunk towards a constant function at large $\lambda$ values rather than towards a linear function.

So, there is certainly shrinkage going on; the smooth in your model uses ~4 EDF when it could have used 14 EDF:

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")

m_pen <- gam(mpg ~ s(disp, bs = "ts", k = 15),
             data = mtcars,
             family = gaussian(),
             method = "REML")

m_unpen <- gam(mpg ~ s(disp, bs = "ts", k = 15, fx = TRUE),
               data = mtcars,
               family = gaussian(),
               method = "REML")

cs <- compare_smooths(m_pen, m_unpen)
draw(cs)
```

[image]

Clearly the estimated smooth has been shrunk away from the unpenalised fit.

However, because of the parameterisation being used for the smooth and the wigglines penalty it's not easy to see where the shrinkage has taken place in terms of the model coefficients. In an alternate parametrisation, the so-called *natural parameterization*, the EDF of the individual basis functions that comprise a smooth are on a scale that demonstrates the shrinkage, but that requires you to change (reparameterise) the basis functions.

If we draw the basis functions weighted by the model coefficients, for both models, you'll get some idea of where the shrinkage has happened:

```r
bs_pen <- m_pen |>
  basis() |>
  draw()
bs_unpen <- m_unpen |>
  basis() |>
  draw()

library("patchwork")

bs_pen + bs_unpen + plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

[image]

It's clear here that many of the basis functions have been shrunk towards zero functions.

Many of the coefficients are close to zero here

```r
> coef(m_pen)                                                                 
 (Intercept)    s(disp).1    s(disp).2    s(disp).3    s(disp).4    s(disp).5 
 20.09062500  -7.78783043  -0.12857499  -1.83287539  -0.17948960  -0.05298061 
   s(disp).6    s(disp).7    s(disp).8    s(disp).9   s(disp).10   s(disp).11 
  0.66157030   0.40009721   0.42537796   0.17876507   0.45666967   0.32813318 
  s(disp).12   s(disp).13   s(disp).14 
 -0.43256068  -2.75386484 -14.07700587
```

indicating low weights for certain functions.

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you very much. The help page says that there is a trade-off between undersmoothing and computational efficiency when setting `k`. I thought that, similar to LASSO, I can set `k`arbitrarily large (provided that I have enough computational ressources) and the basis functions are then shrunk to zero according to the data.

Comment: As you can see in the last figure, the basis functions that are more wiggly (in the right hand plot) are the ones that have been shrunk the most and that these functions have been shrunk to close to zero. But that is for the default thin plate spline basis. You would get different behaviour with the cubic regression spline basis for example, because (crudely put) those functions each have the same wiggliness. In general therefore, it is easier to think about the shrinkage acting to make the estimated function less wiggly (smoother) with higher and higher penalization.

Comment: You can set `k` as large as you have unique data and all else equal the extra wiggliness implied by that many basis functions will get shrunk away, but in general that doesn't mean the coefficients will have to get shrunk towards zero. For the cubic regression spline basis (`bs = "cr"`) for example, a linear fitted function (the most shrunk you can get with that basis) will have many of the basis functions not be zero (assuming the linear function has a slope that is some way from 0), but the shrinkage will result in adjacent coefficients being more similar to one another for example